# Search matching in 2 lists, performance upgrade powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm seachring for help to make something more performant as my method is really stupid but works

I searched a little on stackoverflow but didnt find something matching with my idea

```
ForEach($app in $apps){
    ForEach($removeapp in $applist)
    {
        If ($app.Displayname -like $removeapp.appname) {
            Write-Host "Removing: " $app.Displayname -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        Else{
            Write-Host "Skiping: " $app.Displayname -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
```

I'm basically comparing each one of them what gives me x^y possibillitys whats quite bad and makes it slow any help how to do this faster ?

`$apps` contains every provisiond app package in an Image
for example -> Displayname = Microsoft.ZuneMusic

`$applist` contains those appnames which shell be removed in a CSV 
for example -> Appname = Microsoft.ZuneVideo

And I want to see clearly which are skipped and which are removed.

Comment: Use a `Where-Object` or a contains (`.Contains()` or `-Contains`).

Comment: Please give some background on the data sources (AD?) and sizes. In general, try to stream ([use the pipeline](https://www-red--gate-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/ins-and-outs-of-the-powershell-pipeline/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCCAE%3D#aoh=15548394599308&amp_ct=1554839579437&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=Van%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.red-gate.com%2Fsimple-talk%2Fsysadmin%2Fpowershell%2Fins-and-outs-of-the-powershell-pipeline%2F)) the outer loop (/slowest input), e.g.  by using `$Apps | ForEach-Object {...`.

Comment: I edited my Post for clearification @iRon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would use the regex `-match` operator for this.
Something like below:

```
# build a regex from all the app displaynames joined using the regex OR ("|") character
$appNames = ($apps | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_.DisplayName) }) -join '|'
$applist | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.appname -match $appNames ) {
        Write-Host "Removing: $($_.appname)" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Skipping: $($_.appname)" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Hope that helps